# Equivalent to geom_function in plot_ly R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am building an interactive scatterplot for a shinyApp using `plotly`. I want to include a function of the points in the graph as well. In `ggplot2`, I would use `geom_function`. Do you know  what the equivalent of `geom_function` in `plotly` would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of a `plotly` equivalent to `ggplot2`'s `geom_function` command, but I do happen to have come across a similar problem, when I devised a short function to use as a palliative solution. It is defined using `plotly`'s `add_lines` function to draw the line that represents the graph of a given function (or equation, that is). Here's the code:

```
AddFunctionPlot <- function(p, f = identity, xinf = -10, xsup = 10, numberofsamples = 1000){
    x <- seq(xinf, xsup, length.out = numberofsamples)
    y <- f(x)

    return(add_lines(
    p = p,
    x = x,
    y = y))
}
```

Notice `f` is the function to be plotted and `p` is the plot to which it should be plotted.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `geom_function` to work in plotly, but perhaps workable to use `stat_function` + `plotly::ggplotly` in your situation?

```
set.seed(1492)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(100)), aes(x)) +
  geom_density() +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "polygon", color = "blue", fill = NA, alpha = 0.5) -> a
a
plotly::ggplotly(a)
```